# Search bar + search display controller (UISearchBar) for Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Is there a way to replicate the Search bar + search display controller in iPhone on a blackberry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm kinda brute forcing it. I have a ListField of 10 elements and an EditField to type the text in.

Overridden the keyChar() method in the EditField and every time a key is pressed, I'm just brute force searching through the all the items in the ListField.

Works for now.

Thanks,
Teja